# Событие jQuery только для одного элемента определенного класса

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

Есть абсолютно аналогичные `div` с информацией о заказе (только содержание немного разное). Выпадающий список стилизован по дизайну. Когда я кликаю на `option` селекта одного дива, стиль применяется к другим, так как класс один. Можно ли задать стиль классу только в одном элементе?
Вот то, что я задаю:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.accepted').click(function(){
        jQuery('.selectstatus').css('color', '#0a8eaf');
    });
});
```

Простите, если что-то коряво. Первый день знакомлюсь с jQuery. А по другому, говорят, нельзя задать стиль селекту.

Comment: Селекты лежат внутри этого дива?

Comment: Да, див с общей информацией о заказе. Сколько клиент сделает заказов, столько дивов и появится. А селект для выбора статуса заказа в админке. .selectstatus это класс селекта, .accepted это класс одного из option. Общий див .infoline. Все options по разному расцвечены. Когда выбираю в одном .infoline, в другом также меняется цвет содержимого селекта.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно менять только соответствующего предка, то решение такое:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.accepted').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('.selectstatus').css('color', '#0a8eaf');
    });
});
```

[closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) указывает на ближайшего потомка, соответствующего селектору.

Также обратите внимание на конструкцию `jQuery(function($) {})`. Она позволяет использовать краткий синоним `$` внутри блока, если *jQuery* подключен в режиме *noConflict*. Кроме того данная функция будет вызвана по событию `document.ready`.

Comment: Я неправильно спросил. .selectstatus это класс селекта, а .accepted это класс одного из option. А селект вместе с другой информацией о заказе находится в одном большом диве. В зависимости от того, сколько заказов клиент сделает, столько будет этих общих дивов. Поэтому я классы им всем одинаковые задаю.

Comment: Обновил ответ, посмотрите.

Comment: Огромное наше Вам! Работает!

Comment: Спасибо, еще раз!